# Double complement: moving the indirect complement after the verb

Tags: grammar

See these examples:

> I give *apples* **to my parents**
>
> I give **my parents** *apples*

When changing the indirect object to a pronoun:

> I give *apples* **to them**
>
> I give **them** *apples*

When changing both objects to pronouns:

> I give *them* **to them**

My question is, for this last case, can we say:

> I give **them** *them*

And even when changing only the direct pronoun, can we say:

> I give **my parents** *them*

Comment: In "double complement" (ditransitive) mode for ***give*** with no prepositions, we specify the *indirect* object (the *optional* "recipient") first, followed by the *direct* object (syntactically required "thing given"): But idiomatically we usually don't like using a pronoun (such as ***it***) for the direct object unless the preceding *indirect* object is ***also*** a pronoun. Thus, ***I gave John the money, I gave him the money*** and ***I gave him it***, are all fine, but NOT ***I gave John it***.

Comment: Thanks, so "I give them them" is fine but not "I give my parents them".

Comment: I'd say that *syntactically*, your last example (and mine) are "valid". They're just not "idiomatic". But this is *just my opinion* - which you may want to take with a pinch of salt, given [*my position on ditransitive verb usage*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90531/2637) didn't attract wholehearted support on that related ELU question.

Comment: Funny that you (and others) mentioned "dative". The last time I tried to explain a French grammar rule compared to English ditransitive, I used the "dative" term and someone told me dative just doesn't exist in English and I shouldn't mention it. But to me it really looks like dative, even if the word doesn't change its form. How is it not dative if you drop the preposition and put the word after the verb?

Comment: My first thought there was *I doubt I'd have used the word "dative"*. Checking my text in that link, I see that I *did* - but only because I was referring to the fact that John Lawler's (highly upvoted! :) answer used the term "Dative Alternation" (which didn't mean much to me, so I included a link to a web page *defining* the usage). I'm not particularly interested in terminology for its own sake, and so far as I'm concerned many such words are only really useful if you're studying ***Latin*** or similar (they're not particularly relevant to English, as someone pointed out to you).

Comment: @Destal Whoever told you that is right: English does not have a dative case. In your examples "I Gave apples to my parents" and "I gave apples to them", "my parents" and "them" are not indirect objects, but complements of the preposition "to".